# Normal mappings not working anymore in Vim 9.0 for foreign and special characters

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, nmap

I used to have the following key mappings within `_vimrc`:

```
nmap è "_ddP
nmap ò yaw
nmap à "_dwP
nmap § .n
```

working in Vim 7.4 on Windows and an Italian keyboard. Now, after upgrading to Vim 9.0, they don't work anymore.

They are logged in the output of `verbose map` as:

```
n  <a7>          .n
n  <e0>          "_dwP
n  <e8>          "_ddP
n  <f2>          yaw
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Could you tell us what is the fileencoding of your `.vimrc` file? When your `.vimrc` file is open what is the result of the following two commands `:set fileencoding?`, `:set encoding?`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt `fileencoding=latin1`, `encoding=utf-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the encoding your `.vimrc` to be `latin1` where Vim 9.0 is detecting it as `utf-8`.

One solution is to convert your `.vimrc` to `utf-8`.

You could do that by running the following command on your `.vimrc`.

```
:set fileencoding=utf8
:w
```

After restarting Vim it should run correctly.

Another option is to explicitly tell Vim that your `.vimrc` file is encoded in `latin1` by adding the following line as the first line of your `.vimrc` file:

```
" vim: set fileencoding=latin1 :
```